# Metalic shader glitch in blender

Tags: shaders

I believe there is a glitch in blender. When I move the metalic shader in the principled bsdf it is completely unresponsive. I am unable to make the trash bin metalic. I tried uninstalling blender with no result.

Here is the blend file:
https://dropmefiles.com/VoaUy

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but you forgot to press Use Nodes button in material setup panel:

[image: Metall Use nodes]

Metal cannot have Emission
Your Shader Node has white emission value

[image]

Comment: Thank you @RUben, but I don't understand because the Rim of the garbage can is still white. It is not metallic, even when I use the metallic slider with the "use nodes" selected. It looks like in the photo you provided it is also still white, not metallic.

Comment: The rim is still white. Does anyone know how to make it metallic?

Comment: @Androfski this was because someone setted shader emission value to white ... answer will be updated

Comment: yes I cant figure out how to turn off the emission shader I have been looking everywhere. I feel so stupid it must be really easy. I am googling how to turn off the emission shader but I can't find anything. Will you please tell me how to turn it off

Comment: Just set Emission color to (alpha doesn't matter) https://imgur.com/a/zJC0p0e

Comment: I think this is a glitch because I did that. To demonstrate it I made a new material with the same settings and different result 
(old material)
https://prnt.sc/pmw10v


New material (on the bottom rim)
https://prnt.sc/pmw1gf

I think if you turn on the emission shader it cant go back. Anyways I would like to report this to blender if its the case. Thank you Ruben for your help. Its awesome people like you that help me keep going with blender

Comment: are you sure you can deal with **Viewport Shading**? https://imgur.com/zIUyp6Y